# Iterate through two 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration

i have two 2d arrays and i want to iterate through them both and store the values in a new array
for example:

```
days = [["monday", "11:00"],
        ["monday", "13:00"],
        ["tuesday", "10:00"]]
```

and my other array:

```
modules = [["chemistry", "alkenes"],
           ["biology", "alcohols"],
           ["biology, cells"]]
```

i want the new arrays output to be

```
["monday", "11:00", "Chemistry", "alkenes"]
```

currently my code looks likes this:

```
for x in days:
    newarray = []
    for i in modules:
        newarray.append(x)
        newarray.append(i)
```

but this doesn't work so how would i create this new array

Comment: There is an error in the final list of modules. It should be `["biology", "cells"]` not `["biology, cells"]`

Answer (score 2):

This code should solve your problem

```
days = [["monday", "11:00"],
        ["monday", "13:00"],
        ["tuesday", "10:00"]] 

modules = [["chemistry", "alkenes"],
           ["biology", "alcohols"],
           ["biology", "cells"]]

new_arr = []
for i in range(len(days)):
    merged_arr = []
    merged_arr.append(days[i][0])
    merged_arr.append(days[i][1])
    merged_arr.append(modules[i][0])
    merged_arr.append(modules[i][1])
    new_arr.append(merged_arr)
    
for i in new_arr:
    print(i)
```

Comment: This one is a good answer! Beginner-friendly!